# While loop and if - execute only one time

Tags: php, if-statement

I have following code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
    {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    } else {
        dodaj(strtolower($message), '', 0);
    }
}
```

and I would like to execute function dodaj(); only one time, not a few times. How to do it? Please help, thank you very much.
Greetings.

Comment: The way you wrote the program, how many times do you expect the else condition to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to remember if you called `dodaj`.

```
$called_dodaj = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
    {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    } elseif (!$called_dodaj) {
        dodaj(strtolower($message), '', 0);
        $called_dodaj = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just going to write this, using a flag to indicate whether or not the else if has been gone through

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) statement:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
    {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    } else {
        dodaj(strtolower($message), '', 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I assumed you meant to stop processing results once `dodaj()` was called. However, if you mean that you only want to call `dodaj()` one time, use a flag variable:

```
$dodajCalled = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if(strtolower($message) == $row['question'])
    {
        msg($row['answer']);
        update($row['question']);
    } elseif (!$dodajCalled) {
        dodaj(strtolower($message), '', 0);
        $dodajCalled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the other results from the database?

Comment: Wouldn't loop stop after break? I think he meant not to execute that function but continue loop.

Comment: @d3r1ck - They aren't processed, which is what I think OP wants.

Comment: @streetturtle - Ah. I'll update my answer to show how that could be done.

Comment: If that is what he wants then fine. But I just wonder why do that?

Comment: @d3r1ck - Presumably the business logic would be to update all rows that were before the first non-question row, then call `dodaj()` for the first non-question row, and quit. Not knowing anything about the actual use case, that seems at least plausible.